# Significato di "pazzareglio"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita che da quando lavora con Tom Orecchio è l’unico pensiero luminoso della sua giornata. Quando scaricano gli stracci, riesce sempre a far sparire un lembo di merletto, o uno scampolo di tela. Di notte, scende a lavarli alla fontana, e le confeziona sciarpe scialli e fazzoletti. Fruga tra i rifiuti per lei, per portarle un **pazzareglio** rotto e un trenino di ferro senza ruote.

Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "pazzareglio"? Non ho trovato questa parola su nessun dizionario. Sospetto che si tratti di un termine di origine regionale.

Comment: Su questo dizionario di napoletano ho trovato (per assonanza) [_pazziariéllo_](https://it.glosbe.com/nap/it/pazziari%C3%A9llo) che ha il significato generico di giocattolo

Comment: Anche su questo dizionario di dialetto avellinese per [_pazziariéllo_](http://www.montefalcioneonline.it/sito/images/stories/DIZIONARIO/DIZIONARIO/lettera__p.html) si trova la stessa definizione

Answer (score 1):

Il termine *pazzareglio* effettivamente non si trova ma cercando per assonanza una parola simile ho trovato che esiste il termine del dialetto napoletano *[pazziariello](https://it.glosbe.com/nap/it/pazziari%C3%A9llo)* che ha il significato generico di giocattolo.

> pazziariéllo
>  giocattolo { noun masculine }

Anche in questo dizionario di dialetto avellinese il termine *[pazziariello](http://www.montefalcioneonline.it/sito/images/stories/DIZIONARIO/DIZIONARIO/lettera__p.html)* ha lo stesso significato:

> PAZZIARIELLO: Sost. Giocattolo.

In [questo blog](http://cronachetauriniche.blogspot.com/2009/04/) si può leggere la seguente frase:

> Alla fine qualcuno decise per tutti e si andò avanti, ma, come si dice
>   a Napoli, fù come dare 'o *pazziariello* 'mmano a 'è creature, il
>   **giocattolo** in mano ai bambini. Oggi, centocinquanta anni dopo, il
>   giocattolo non funziona più, e quello che era un popolo bambino non è
>   mai cresciuto.

Il termine giocattolo si adatta perfettamente al contesto da te citato:

> per portarle un giocattolo rotto e un trenino di ferro senza ruote.